# Help with percentage

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Can someone please explain how to calculate "percent more than" and "percent less than"?

I know $35$ is $75$ percent more than $20$ - but no idea how to calculate it.

Also trying to figure out how to find percent less than for: $120$ is what percent less than $200$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $35$ is $75\%$ more than $20$ because
$$20 + (0.75)\cdot 20=20+15=35.$$
That is, if you compute $75\%$ of $20$ and add it to $20$, you get $35$. Let's see what $75\%$ less than $20$ is. Following the same logic as above, we should compute $75\%$ of $20$ and then *subtract* it from $20$:
$$20-(0.75)\cdot 20 = 20-15 = 5.$$
That procedure is really all you need to know. $y$ is $r$ percent more than $x$ if 
$$y=x+\left(\frac{r}{100}\right)\cdot x$$
and $y$ is $r$ percent less than $x$ if 
$$y=x-\left(\frac{r}{100}\right) \cdot x.$$
Your second question asks: $120$ is what percent less than $200$? This is a "percent less than" problem, so we'll use the second equation that has the minus sign. We want to find the value of $r$ that makes the sentence "$120$ is $r$ percent less than $200$" true. So we see that $120$ is taking the place of $y$ and $200$ is taking the place of $x$. You're asked to find $r$, which you should now be able to do with some algebra.

Comment: @queens718 You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> $35$ is $75$ percent more than $20$

This implies $35-20=75$% of $20$

> $120$ is what percent less than $200$

Here if the answer is $x$%, then we have the equation $200-120=x$% of $200$

> Can someone please explain how to calculate "percent more than" and "percent less than"?

If $x$ is $m$ % more than $y$ then it implies $x-y=m$% of $y$

AND

If $p$ is $n$ % less than $q$ then it implies $q-p=n$% of $q$